# Registering kafkalistenerContainers with KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I want to pragmatically control when to start/stop my kafka listeners.So looking through some previous posts and discussions it looks like I could use KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer(id).stop()  to do that .However I verified that  no containers are registered with my KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry bean.How do I register  my container with KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry ?

```
    @Autowired
     KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry;


            @Bean
            public KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry() {
                kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry =  new KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry();
                return kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry;
            }


            @Bean

            public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> 
                kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
                        ConsumerFactory<String, SpecificRecord> kafkaConsumerFactory
                        ) {
                    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, SpecificRecord> factory 
                = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
                factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
              factory.getContainerProperties().setTransactionManager(kafkaTransactionManager());
                    factory.getContainerProperties().setIdleEventInterval(60000L);
                    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
                    factory.setRetryTemplate(getRetryTemplate());
                    factory.setConcurrency(2);
                    factory.getContainerProperties().setErrorHandler(rawLogsErrorHandler(KafkaTemplate));
                    return factory;
                }
            @Bean
        KafkaTransactionManager<String,SpecificRecord> kafkaTransactionManager() {
            return  new KafkaTransactionManager<>(producerFactory());
        }

    @Bean
        public RetryTemplate getRetryTemplate() {
            RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
            FixedBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
            backOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(1000);
            RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
            retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);
            retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
            retryTemplate.registerListener(retryListener());
            return retryTemplate;
        }



        @Bean
        public LoggingErrorHandler rawLogsErrorHandler(KafkaTemplate<String,SpecificRecord> kafkaTemplate) {
    return new LoggingErrorHandler() {
                @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
                @Override
                public void handle(Exception thrownException, ConsumerRecord<?,?> record) {

    // record send to a dead letter here
    //stop all listeners
kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.stop();
    }

    @Bean
        public LogReceiver receiver() {
            return new LogReceiver();
        } 

    // and on Logreciever class


    public class Logreciever 
        @KafkaListener(topics = RAWLLOGTOPIC,id="rawLogConsumer",containerFactory="kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
        public void onMessage(@Payload Log log, 
                @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition,
                @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) Long offset) throws Exception
                 {

    //processing code

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/_reference.html#kafkalistener-lifecycle). Only containers for `@KafkaListener`s are registered in the registry.

Containers retrieved from the factory as `@Bean`s are registered with the application context.

If you manually create containers using the container factory, no registration is performed.

Comment: I am creating  the  containers manually since I have some custom error handling and  retry logic .Can this be done without  manually creating the containers?. What is the  best way to handle the lifecycle of these consumers in that case.

Comment: Edit the question to show how you are creating the containers.

Comment: Kafkatemplate I am using is transactional and  I am letting the container send the offsets to transaction .The retries ,error logging and  transactional semantics are working

Comment: Ah; so you are using `@KafkaListener` - the problem is you are looking at the wrong registry - you don't need to define one; the framework declares one with a bean name `KafkaListenerConfigUtils.KAFKA_LISTENER_ENDPOINT_REGISTRY_BEAN_NAME`. Just remove yours and auto wire the default one.

Comment: Thanks Gary . That  worked . Should we add that as part  of spring-kafka documentation .I ran into another endpoint is already registered with id  exception but this post https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/236 helped to get past that

Comment: It says `Instead, they are registered with an infrastructure bean of type KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.` - I will enhance the documentation to make sure it's clear that the framework manages that bean. (Infrastructure means that, but it might not be obvious to all).

Comment: My code is executing  kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.stop() the method on certain business condition but @kafkalistener is still  consuming message even after the  container shutdown property timeout is passed . I am calling the stop method from within an errorhandler.Edited to add  the code snippet

Comment: Stopping the container will only prevent it from fetching new records; it will still pass already fetched messages to the listener. Use a `ContainerStoppingErrorHandler` to discard the remaining records from the last poll (and they will be refetched on the next start).